# Normalized absorbance/transmittance definition

Tags: physical-chemistry, spectroscopy, absorption

In the absorption spectroscopy we can calculate transmittance $T$ of a given sample by comparing how the intensity of the incident beam $I_{0}$ is decreased with the distance (Lambert-Beer Law).

$A = -\ln{\frac{I}{I_{0}}}=\alpha L$

where $A$ is absorbence, $T = 1 -A$, $\alpha$ is an absorption coefficient and $L$ is the distance.

But I encountered something called Normalized transmittence I don't really understand how can I get it from measured data. Normalized how? It appears in scientific articles but I couldn't find any good source explaining it really.

I read that I should divide my measured $I$ by reference intensity (it can fluctuate so it is measured along the way too). So the normalized absorbance would be $A = -\ln{\frac{I}{I_{0}^2}}$ or just by definition $A = -\ln{\frac{I}{I_{0}}} $

Can anyone help me please?

The spectra then look like this:
[image]

[https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Hydrogen-cyanide-H-13-C-14-N-2-3-rotational-vibrational-band-spectrum-obtained-by_fig4_242279131]

Comment: This was posted by you and got an answer that you accepted: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/685025/313612. Is there something that is specifically not being addressed?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a cross-posted question from https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/685025

Comment: [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall the more familiar definition of light transmittance

$T = \frac{I}{I_o}$, many instruments quote percent transmittance as

$\%T = 100\frac{I}{I_o}$

Normalized transmittance is nothing but the maximum measured transmittance set to unity. This is easy to accomplish. Suppose you have 2000 data points (y-values) in your spectrum collected as a function of wavelength. Locate the *maximum* value of transmittance, say it was 95% or 0.95 in your data set (depending what was collected experimentally). Now divide the entire y-values with 95.65% or 0.9565. With that your maximum, transmittance will be exactly equal to 1  and the rest of the values will be less than 1. This process is called normalization.

It is just for convenience when you are comparing a lot of spectra.

Comment: Upvoted, but it is not clear why the OP first posted at physics SE, accepted an answer and then came here. Modern double beam-in-time instruments are rather good, so double beam-in-space spectrometers are not necessarily preferred for source noise performance.

Comment: @EdV, I think the OP was confused how to normalize the *experimental* data. I did not know it was posted twice.

Comment: Yes, that is what I figured. But the HCN IR spectrum was apparently used to calibrate a laser system, based on what I find when searching. In the old days, a pulsed laser might have been used to pump a tunable dye laser and then pulse-to-pulse fluctuations in the pump laser’s output, typically a few percent, had to be normalized out. Missing and runt pulses were especially annoying and experimental data had to be corrected for those. I used to use a window comparator to ensure collection of data from non-defective laser pulses.